# Backbone.js jQuery Mobile CSS issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I am working on simple application where I am using backbone.js for routing and jQuery mobile for CSS. But when ever I change any view CSS is not loaded.

Here is my Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/vendor/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <title>Test App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
    <div data-role="header">

        <h1>App.IO</h1>
        <a href="#new" data-icon="edit" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn-right" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-ajax="false">New</a>

        <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-active" data-ajax="false">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about"  data-icon="grid" data-ajax="false">About</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div id="main" data-role="content">

    </div>


    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h3>
        © Shekhar Gulati 2013
    </h3>
</div>
```

```
        <ul id="list"  data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search items..." data-inset="true">

        </ul>

    </script>


    <script type="text/x-mustache-template" id="new-template">

        <form id="itemForm">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter name of item" value="">

            <label for="description">Description:</label>
            <input type="text" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Enter description" value="">
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

    </script>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/backbone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/backbone-localstorage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/mustache.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

Here is my app.js
    (function(){

```
var MyApp =  {};
window.MyApp = MyApp;

var template = function(name) {
    return Mustache.compile($('#'+name+'-template').html());
};

MyApp.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({

});

MyApp.Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : MyApp.Item,
    localStorage : new Store('items'),
});

MyApp.ItemsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template : template('items'),

    initialize : function(){
            this.items = new MyApp.Items();
            this.items.fetch();
        },

        render : function(){
            this.$el.append(this.template);
            this.items.each(this.renderItem,this);
            return this;
        },

        renderItem : function(item){
            this.$('#list').append('<li><h3>'+item.get('name')+'</h3><p>'+item.get('description')+'</p></li>');
        }
});

MyApp.NewItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template : template("new"),

    events : {
        "click #submit" : "storeItem",
    },


    render : function(){
        this.$el.append(this.template);
        return this;
    },

    storeItem : function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.collection = new MyApp.Items();
        this.collection.create({name : $("#name").val() , description : $("#description").val()});
    }

});

MyApp.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize : function(options){
            this.el = options.el;
    },
    routes : {
        "" : "home",
        "home" : "home",
        "new" : "new",
        "about" : "about",

    },

    home : function(){
        console.log('in home() ...');
        var itemsView = new MyApp.ItemsView();
        this.el.empty();
        this.el.append(itemsView.render().el);
    },

    new : function(){
        console.log('in new()...');
        this.el.empty();
        this.el.append(new MyApp.NewItemView().render().el);
    },

    about : function(){
        console.log('in about()...');
        this.el.empty();
    },



});

var router = new MyApp.Router({el : $('#main')});
Backbone.history.start();

})(jQuery);
```

Now each time I move from "#home" view to "#new" view or vice versa , jQuery Mobile CSS is not applied. I have also created a github repository so you can use that as well https://github.com/shekhargulati/stackoverflow-backbone-jquery-mobile-issue.

Comment: From my brief expedition in jQuery Mobile land, I could vaguely remember that you have to call some function to `enhance` the element if you add the element after the page has been loaded. See this: http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-refresh and it has the same mechanism for all elements. jQuery mobile is **NOT** CSS by the way.

Comment: What I mean was that I only intend to use its CSS features. I don't want to use routing facility.

Comment: Can you recommend where in app.js I should call refresh method. I can't seem to figure out

Comment: Well ok if you only need the CSS part then you have to follow jQuery mobile element structures. Take button for example, apart from `ui-btn-active` class you also needs `ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-a` and inner span element with class `ui-btn-inner` with another span with class `ui-btn-text` that contains the actual text for the button. If I were you, I wound't bother and [go](http://topcoat.io/) [use](http://purecss.io/) [other](http://getbootstrap.com/) [libraries](http://foundation.zurb.com/) [instead](http://maker.github.io/ratchet/).